# Using PyDictionary to check if a word exists

Tags: python

Very new to the PyDictionary library, and have had some trouble finding proper documentation for it. So, I've come here to ask:

A) Does anybody know how to check if a word (in english) exists, using PyDictionary?

B) Does anybody know of some more full documentation for PyDictionary?

Comment: Have you read the page at https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary ?

Comment: Yes I have read the page, but am looking for further documentation, if it exists.

Comment: I think the only documentation available is the code itself: https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/blob/master/PyDictionary/core.py

Answer (score 2):

To further expound on what @Daniele stated, you can just pass True to the meaning function. If the word is not found in the dictionary, the function returns None.

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

def check_if_word_in_dictionary(word):
    dictionary = PyDictionary()

    if dictionary.meaning(word,True) is None:
        print(f"It appears '{word}' is NOT a word found in the dictionary.")
    else:
        print(f"You're in luck, '{word}' IS found in the dictionary!")

check_if_word_in_dictionary("fingle")
```

**Output:** It appears 'fingle' is not a word found in the dictionary.

```
check_if_word_in_dictionary("finger")
```

**Output:** You are in luck, 'finger' IS found in the dictionary!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the code here in theory there is this:

meaning(term, disable_errors=False)

so you should be able to pass True to avoid printing the error in case the word is not in the dictionary. I tried but I guess the version I installed via pip does not contains that code...